# Append a node's siblings using Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, dom, cheerio

I have a div containing an h3 and some divs. I want to essentially wrap all of the divs together in one container div, but Cheerio doesn't have a wrap or wrap-together function.

Right now I'm appending the container div, making it a sibling of the divs that need to be its children. But I'm at a loss as to how to move its siblings into this container. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
$("div.container").append($this.siblings("div"));
```

Essentially "append to this node, the div siblings of this node." But I can't figure out how to make the self reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always create a new wrapper and move all the div children from the original container to the new one:

```
// Create a wrapper
var newDiv = $('<div>');

// Move all divs from #container to the wrapper
newDiv.append($('#container').find('div'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5w93bs0f/

Comment: Thanks, using a var was a good idea. I'm so used to xpath I got hung up on the idea of using a sibling axis   :\